# Issue with getting cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get a cell value from a google spreadsheet so I wrote a function but it returns me just a message which is "#Error".

```
        function getCellValue(input) {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
          var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
          var range = sheet.getRange(input);
          var data = range.getValues()
          return data;
        }
```

Comment: Is input a string in the R1C1 form or is it a reference to another cell?  getRange in the form that you have used it requires a string so your formula should be something like =getCellValue("A1")

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be authorized to access that API. In your code, you should have authorization check first. Please find the below link for reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) to know how to troubleshoot your script.

> When your script encounters an error, an error message is displayed in a red bar at the top of the screen. The message is accompanied by a line number used for troubleshooting. There are two basic types of errors displayed in this way: [*syntax errors*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#syntax_errors) and [*runtime errors*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#runtime_errors).

You may also look into the [Stackdriver logging service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) and the more basic [Logger service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging) that's built in to the Apps Script editor to debug your code.